# Unable to use ElementTree to modify contents within CDATA in body of XML

Tags: python, xml, jboss, elementtree

I am currently attempting to POST an XML file to Jboss within a python script that I've created, however am running into an error relating to namespace on jboss console when the method to POST executes.

Note: Prior to my attempt to POST, I have used ElementTree to parse the XML/change some fields within the body of the XML.

Note: There are some soap headers that surround the xml body when the request is sent (successfully) in SOAPUI (see below) and I have excluded these in the xml file I am reading from in order to parse/edit the xml as needed.

My goal is either to:

1. Find a way to simply include the soap headers in the XML file prior to parsing (ElementTree will not edit the XML it if I include them currently)

OR

2. Rid the 'No namespace' error on the element with the the soap headers excluded.

**Method in script to post request:**

```
def fire_post_request():
      xml_file = "updated.xml"
      headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml'}

# Open the XML file.
      with open(xml_file) as xml:
    # Give the object representing the XML file to requests.post.
            r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/path/to/whererulesserviceisrunning', data=xml)

      print (r.content)
```

**Error on Jboss console:**

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>No namespace on "SomeDefinition" element.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**Current Structure of XML without surrounding soap headers (parsedxml.xml)**:

```
 <SomeDefinition>
  <Channel>....</Channel>

  <Rulesmsg>

      <body>
      .... 
      </body>
    </service>
  </Rulesmsg>
</SomeDefinition>
```

**Soap headers that I've excluded from XML file because with them, ElementTree doesn't let me edit the XML:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rule="somewebsitepath0" xmlns:ws="somewebsitepath1" xmlns:buss="somewebsitepath2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:Respond>
         <ws:Message>
            <buss:SourceReference>11122</buss:SourceReference>
            <buss:Content>**<![CDATA[**

.....XML BODY WOULD GO HERE.....

**]]>**</bus:Content>
            <bus:MessageTypeId>3243242</bus:MessageTypeId>
         </ws:Message>
      </ws:Respond>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You say *"I have used ElementTree to parse the XML/change some fields within the body of the XML"*, and *"ElementTree doesn't let me edit the XML"*, but ElementTree is not used in the code in the question.

Comment: Hi @mzjn, My apologies. What I realized is that CDATA was the big problem for me here. When I attempted to parse/edit the xml, I was unable to convert properly because of the CDATA content that existed in the body of the xml. I am now using lxml to convert the data within CDATA to a string first, and then attempt to use ElementTree to edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to CDATA not being able to be kept as CDATA after the use of ElementTree. I ended up using lxml library to retain the CDATA as per my requirements.